# How to debug an AWS RDS Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an Amazon RDS instance.
It has Multi AZ enabled.

Some other specs:

Instance and IOPS

Instance Class

```
db.t2.micro
DB Instance General Purpose (SSD)
IOPS disabled
60 GB
```

Lately it's been lagging really hard.
Notice the latency on read, write, and queue depth.

There is no change in Read Throughput or Write Throughput.

Can anyone assist in debugging this?

[image]

Comment: What database engine? What do the t2 cpu credits look like?

Comment: CPU Credit Usage seems fine. averaging 50.

Answer (score 0):

What's your database engine? If you are using MYSQL, check with profiler application to find which parts make latency.

Comment: Can you add detail here? What's the profile application? The database is InnoDB.